# Simple integral representation for a beta function with more than two variables

Tags: cv.complex-variables, integration, special-functions, closed-form-expressions, periods

The beta function $B(x,y)=\dfrac{\Gamma(x)\,\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$ can be written for $\Re x, \Re y > 0$ symmetrically as $$ B(x,y) = \int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12}(\frac12-t)^{x-1}(\frac12+t)^{y-1}\,dt.$$
Let us define more generally $B(x,y,z):=\dfrac{\Gamma(x)\,\Gamma(y)\,\Gamma(z)}{\Gamma(x+y+z)}=B(x,y)\cdot B(x+y,z)$
and likewise for more variables.

> **Is it possible to write $B(x,y,z)$ in a similar way as a simple (i.e. one-variable) integral**?

I guess it would be asking too much if requiring moreover the integrand to be (more or less) symmetric in $x,y,z$. That is, other than a trivial mean $\frac16(B(x,y,z)+\cdots+B(z,y,x))$.

Comment: Seems like some flavor of Selberg's integral could help?

Answer (score 2):

In view of the analogy with the relation between Gauss sums and Jacobi sums,
one should have $$\int_{0\le x,y,z\le1, x+y+z=1}(1-x)^{a-1}(1-y)^{b-1}(1-z)^{c-1}dxdy=B(a,b,c),$$ and similarly with more variables (I didn't check). Of course this is double integral, not a one-variable one as you ask.

Comment: This seems indeed a well motivated guess to directly generalize the beta integral, but as you say, my question is if a *simple* integral is possible.